# Array without fixed size

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I started studying C# a while back, and I always heard that if I do not have the size of the array, I should always choose list, because arrays can't be initialized without the size.

That being said, I have tried to instance a new array with no size value, and it just works.

```
string Input = "1-2-3";
string[] Lista = new string[] { };
Lista = Input.Split('-'); 
for(int i = 0; i < Lista.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Lista[i]);
}
```

Output: 1 2 3.

Do I really have to choose list over array, or it is an outdated concept?

Comment: Is it wrong to use it as I did in the example?

Comment: Indeed, you create an array of size 0, which you then throw away when you create a new one (the output of string.Split is an array)

Comment: List<T> is a wrapper around an array of T.  It's just there to manage the complexity of using the array to store T in it.  (resize, copy, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example above is wrong.

When you do `Lista = Input.Split('-')`, you overwrite the old array (empty one) with a new one that has 3 items.

In order for you to resize an array you have to do the following:

```
string[] Lista = new string[] { "str1", "str2" };
// Resize array
Array.Resize<string>(ref Lista, 3);
// Set value for new elements
Lista[2] = "str3";
```

*Be careful*, based on the MS documentation ([Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=netcore-3.1)) we have the following:

> This method allocates a new array with the specified size, copies
> elements from the old array to the new one, and then replaces the old
> array with the new one. array must be a one-dimensional array.

As such I would be extremely careful to use such operation as it is CPU intensive. Your best alternative is to use a `List`.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays *can't* be initialized without a size. When you did `string[] Lista = new string[] { };`, you created an empty string array. If you did `string[] Lista = new string[] { "Hello", "World" };`, you'd have created an array of two strings. The size is implied from the contents of the initialization list in `{...}`.

When you do `Lista = Input.Split('-');` later, you *replace* the original empty array with the new array that comes from `Input.Split()`.

If you want an array into which you can add / remove elements, [use a `List<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1)